# How to display the username of the current logged in user from database using php

Tags: php, mysql, email, session, server

Hi am trying to display the name of user that just logged in, Now when i sign up it works but when i login it does not work, please help.

This it the php code at the top of the index.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

  if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: login.php');
  }

  if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header("location: login.php");
  }
?>
```

This is the code that was meant to display the name that is in the index.php

```
<?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['username']); ?>
```

This is my server.php

```
<?php
session_start();

// initializing variables
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array(); 

// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'register');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
  $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
  $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

  // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
  // by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array
  if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
  if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
  if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
  if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
    array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
  }

  // first check the database to make sure 
  // a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
  $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  if ($user) { // if user exists
    if ($user['username'] === $username) {
      array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
    }

    if ($user['email'] === $email) {
      array_push($errors, "email already exists");
    }
  }

  // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
  if (count($errors) == 0) {

    $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

    $query = "INSERT INTO user (username, email, password) 
              VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: index.php');
  }
}

// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

  if (empty($email)) {
    array_push($errors, "Email is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
      header('location: index.php');
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }
  }
}

?>
```

But is like i have discovered that it is because there is no input code that has name="username" in my login.php

yeah, Remember the user is logging in with email and password not username and password, thank you.

Comment: after verifying a logged user, before setting a session call the username then set a session by the actual values got from the db for that verified user.

Comment: my concern is that you should use always prepared statements for your mysqli, because of sql injection

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will invariably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code needs. You will have to enable sessions if you have not done so.

```
//enable sessions if you have not done so
  //session_start();
 //$_SESSION['username'] = 'nancy';
 $_SESSION['username'] = $results['username'];
```

You can then echo it as follows

```
<?php
//enable sessions if you have not done so
      //session_start();
 echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']);
 ?>
```

hence your code will look like

```
// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

  if (empty($email)) {
    array_push($errors, "Email is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {

//session_start();
     // $_SESSION['username'] = 'nancy';
 $_SESSION['username'] = $results['username'];

      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
      header('location: index.php');
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }
  }
}
```

Please am sure that you are not using this code in production. Php has a native way of hashing password and you are using deprecated md5.

You can refer on my previous answers on how to write login based on php way.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057470/what-are-the-best-practices-for-password-submission/55061317#55061317) **As for sql injection, I will suggest that you used prepared statements as its more safer**