# PHP password verify is not functioning properly in MySQLi

Tags: php, forms, session, mysqli, passwords

I am able to hash and verify a password like this

```
<?php
    $password ="passss.com";
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    if (password_verify('passss.com', $hash)) {
         echo 'Password is valid!';
    } else {
      echo 'Invalid password.';
    }
?>
```

But when I tried to do same thing in the querying of data from MySQL I am always getting `Invalid password`

I simply created the `$hash` in a PHP file and inserted it into MySQL table manually.

```
if (!isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    die('Please fill both the username and password field!');
}
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, userpassword FROM users WHERE useremail = ?')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $userpassword);
        $stmt->fetch();
        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $userpassword)) {
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            echo "Password is valid";
        } else {
            echo "Invalid password.";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect username!';
    }
}
```

Comment: var_dump the hashed password, what does it show? Plus, check the password column's length; what is it?

Comment: What is the size of your password hash column?

Comment: The size is `varchar(255)` but I am able to insert the hashed value into the table properly

Comment: So why are you checking for the password verification with a POST array if you entered/saved it manually?

Comment: I want to assure you guys that Password is in the database but when I want to check login trough MySQLi it is not verifying

Comment: What I forgot to also add was; are you entering the hash in the form or the plain text you posted as a variable? Your question is starting to be unclear (for me) and knowing details.

Comment: No I entered the hashed value like `$2y$10$4kXej/WaHMFZf37Ru5Ed5eheUaKRRvfqa6jE18XcSP1lH13unSS2y` into the cell

Comment: just a quick question: you use `bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);` and `useremail = ?` in the `prepare`, that's a bit confusing

Comment: Right. I second what @jibsteroos mentions above. Plus, I asked about the POST array's value and origin earlier; that wasn't answered nor was the question updated to contain the form. This might just be a typographical error made somewhere.

Comment: Please provide a dump of `$_POST['password']` & `$userpassword`. The hashed value you gave matches the password for me, but we don't understand where did you get that hash from, or what is in the post.

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure that you properly hash the password using php builting functions. something like

```
$password=$_POST['password'];
$options = array("cost"=>4);
$hashPassword = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,$options);
```

// here pass **$hashPassword** and insert into database

I have already answered this question in the link below where you can learn to register, verify password hash and then login

[What are the best practices for password submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057470/what-are-the-best-practices-for-password-submission/55061317#55061317)

Comment: Thanks for reply Nancy, but as I said I hashed the password by this way `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`